# Как сделать так, чтобы до того, как пользователь авторизуется, он не мог нажимать на ссылки в панели, а после — смог?

Tags: javascript, аутентификация

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/WbThPgBue3P4Y5goEi84iEZkOhzO3nl0xovlSiy1-Z3oM8H8jUHsuLZ7v8vBtQMtVdpOvzAxyiENXwWWKQM22VYR14-pfAtnDGwGJrHX72nUcHql8KZ_5SAl-_kLdnvuuuyY2IyswxZjn0cmGSncr9kYnwJl9erF8BIUAChhxkzvGX7vNOLEa-m7qwkzAx-Nmyqw4MrGM5ScbARGONtqwIOuxY83ErOBrjde7eLY5t4YUoJCG3W2N2GhkRGqb8ahHae6ZDBbqwBU9sqRehr6SyX1IBqTeWzLErsL1FsIN_UIAmxug1adsgUEse2TpIDrbpdIwkDd7co4lMMBop3Dmw74LceHWrIfqmfmM_LQg2ldmXFk6lEuDoTMyCfxMvtUfTYyplFjzyrytZnOTkaGSUFqsTm4X9llwyvn2TjXHgrQiFJwshVchTIyMAmeoPRkPG6Q-hfNLSMPPjKeLXVIr70Sjnn7ejJ16yeRxcmd3hv8aMiGu-9ncoUIkK0PhLo0-nuEeQslF_u1VOsNuuq3nxyFChCAl95h_UAywCPT2hMbImrwlFjmhqIYGyGm4AyCoXCxS3JciNjNm8ILa9CvPX3zqUygQtObJ3cBsMRq9YZP2l8PJYpJ7y5hxG5CEAi7AtBhp0dKJGUF9gA3mYGLTOzsoegEpaVkxrSWI8ZGmYTUAV3S1sMSVV20qV0j=s512-no?authuser=0">
    <title>Inst-Post Searcher</title>
    <style>
        body {
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(to bottom, #333 20%, #2a2929 90%, #808080);
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#333), to(#808080), color-stop(0.5, #2a2929));
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333', endColorstr='#808080');
            background-size: 100% 106%;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 98%;
        }

        .tbody {
            height: 99.8%;
            width: 99.7%;
        }

        .politics {
            color: #c46d04;
            text-decoration: none;
            position: fixed;
            font-size: 1.0vw;
            top: 94%;
            background: none;
            border: none;
        }

        .title {
            color: #c46d04;
            text-align: center;
            margin-top: -2.5%;
        }

        .menu {
            height: 82%;
            width: 200px;
            position: fixed;
        }

            .menu ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 200px;
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
                position: fixed;
                margin-top: -0.4%;
                overflow: auto;
                height: 100%;
            }

            .menu a {
                display: block;
                color: #c46d04;
                padding: 8px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
                border-top: 1px dashed #c46d04;
                border-bottom: 1px dashed #c46d04;
                border-right: 1px dashed #c46d04;
                border-left: 5px solid #c46d04;
            }

                .menu a:hover {
                    background-color: #c46d04;
                    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.80);
                }

        .workspace {
            height: 82%;
            width: 89.66%;
            top: 9%;
            position: absolute;
            left: 9.8%;
        }

        .footer {
            height: 10%;
            width: 102%;
            position: fixed;
            z-index: 1;
            background-color: #333;
            top: 91%;
            right: -1%;
        }

        hr {
            background-color: #c46d04;
            border-color: #c46d04;
            border-radius: 100px;
        }

        .lowerfixedline {
            position: fixed;
            top: 90%;
            width: 105%
        }

        .workspace h1 {
            color: #c46d04;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .workspace a {
            color: #01006c;
            text-decoration: none;
            background: none;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/ru_RU/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v8.0&appId=295566758542379" nonce="mVu6CAJJ"></script>
    <div class="tbody">
        <div class="fb-login-button" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-layout="default" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="false" data-width=""></div>
        <div class="title">
            <h1><nobr>Inst-Post Searcher</nobr></h1>
            <hr size="2" />
        </div>
        <div class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href='@Url.Page("/Index")'>Поиск</a></li>
                <li><a href='@Url.Page("/added-users")'>Пользователи</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <hr class="lowerfixedline" size="2" />
            <a style="left: 33%" class="politics" href='@Url.Page("/terms-of-use")'><nobr>Условия использования</nobr></a>
            <a style="left: 43.5%" class="politics" href='@Url.Page("/privacy-policy")'><nobr>Политика конфиденциальности</nobr></a>
            <a style="left: 57.5%" class="politics" href='@Url.Page("/developer-contacts")'><nobr>Контакты разработчика</nobr></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @RenderBody()
</body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]
Как сделать так, чтобы до того, как пользователь авторизуется, он не мог нажимать на ссылки в панели, а после - смог? Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры кода, а также скажите, куда именно мне его нужно вставить?

Comment: Если это ссылки не для глаз постороннего, то их там быть не должно!

Comment: Тут что ваш код, что скрины - вообще ни к чему.. Как у вас авторизация работает? Что за фрейморк/cms/etc..?

Comment: То что вы предлагаете является прямым нарушением UX. Подумайте дважды, приятно ли пользователю будет видеть кнопку, которая нажимается, но ничего не делает?

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю у вас это Razor или что там. Тогда предлагаю вам рендерить страницу без указания ссылок.

по типу

```
if (@autorized) {
  <a style="left: 33%" class="politics" href="#" onclick="return false;"><nobr>Условия использования</nobr></a>
} else {
  <a style="left: 33%" class="politics" href='@Url.Page("/terms-of-use")'><nobr>Условия использования</nobr></a>
}
```

у вас будут генеривоваться пустые ссылки если пользователь не авторизован.